# cgf_gpio.h: No such file or directory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3

I am writing a LKM(linux kernel module) for mpu6050 on raspberry pi3.
when I run the "make" command it shows the error like:

> cgf_gpio.h: No such file or directory

here are the all libraries I have used in my .h file:

> #include <cfg_gpio.h>
> #include <linux/module.h>
> #include <linux/init.h>
> #include <linux/kernel.h>
> #include <cfg_type.h>
> #include <mach/platform.h>
> #include <mach/gpio_desc.h>

libraries with linux are compiled easily but without linux like cfg_type.h gives this

> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.63-v7+/include/linux

what I have tried?

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get upgrade

> sudo apt-get install libconfig-dev

and many more like these but none of them works what should I do now?

Comment: Isn’t it a driver already in the Linux kernel?

Comment: In case you missed it: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/imu/inv_mpu6050.

Comment: Where actually is cfg_gpio.h or cgf_gpio.h or whatever you called it?

Comment: @Ian Abbott here is the link from where I have copied the project and tried to run it. At first, I think it was because of the make file mistake.. so I changed the make file and compile only the mpu6050 file but it threw the error of the library.